# gcm - is it possible to know if the message is sent to an offline device?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Currently, sending a message from my server gives me an OK response, meaning the message has been forwarded to GCM and it will be received by the device unless it's offline, which it will receive once it's online. Would it be possible to determine if the device hasn't received it yet because it's currently offline?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Can I ask why you need that information? GCM is designed to essentially deliver notifications. What they are not supposed to be used for is anything time critical or important to the function of your app. You are just supposed to deliver messages with it which may or may not be delivered and possibly with considerable delay. Checking if a message has been already been delivered kind of goes against that idea.

Comment: I think we're relying too much on the interchange between the server and the client app thru push notifications. What we want to achieve is in case the receiver device is offline and thus can't receive the message, we'll send it via SMS. That's why we want to be able to tell if the receiver is currently offline and so can't receive the push notification via GCM.

Comment: That will never work properly automatically. Look at common messenger applications like hangouts or Whats App. You choose when sending the message if it is supposed to be delivered through SMS or over the internet.  The only thing that Hangouts or Whats App does for you is track if a person is online and and automatically switch from online to sms if the recipient has sent you an sms. What you should do is this:

Comment: If the user has chosen delivery over the internet send the push notification -> the recipient calls a web service as soon as he has received it -> after that a push notification delivers the result to the sender and marks the message as delivered. Do not automatically switch to sms.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to query the status of a GCM message after it is sent. One option would be to have your app request a [delivery receipt](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref), or manually ack the message via HTTP. Then if your server doesn't get the ack within a certain time you could then send via SMS.

As you then end up sending some messages via GCM and SMS, you will need code to de-duplicate the messages in your app.

Answer (score 0):

now GCM support "message delivered to device", just set "delivery_receipt_requested": true and deal eith incomming ack..

[see this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using HTTP protocol for sending messages.

If you use XMPP instead, and add `"delivery_receipt_requested": true` to your JSON, GCM will send a Delivery message to you upon Delivery. (you can find the documents [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#receipts))
Otherwise you have to handle it manually on HTTP.